# Tomcat: how to link http:\\localhost\myFolder to C:\testFolder

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I want to link a folder to custom url.

For example, I have a folder: `C:\testFolder`

I want this: when you type `http:\\localhost:8080\myFolder` tomcat actually shows `testFolder`.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404528/map-external-directory-to-web-xml

Comment: Note: Windows file paths (such as `C:\testFolder`) use backslashes \. Pretty much *everything else* (including URLs) use slashes `/`. So it should be `http://localhost:8080/myFolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit server.xml located under TOMCAT_HOME/conf

It contains tag like:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

change the value of `appBase` to `C:/testFolder`

Pay attention on the slash I used. Use forward slash although you are on Windows.